# letsencrypt pan-domain certificate

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

I applied for the certificate of **1991421.cn**, but I found that I can use this certificate to **static.1991421.cn**'s services.

I am very confused, what is the difference between this certificate and the pan-domain certificate such as *.1991421.cn.

I originally wanted to apply for two certificates, **1991421.cn** and **static.1991421.cn**, so as to use the corresponding two WEB services, but I found that 1991421.cn can be satisfied with one certificate.

Answer (score 0):

~~I think, what u can't use the certificate of **.example.com* for *https://example.com*, because this link not comparable with mask.~~ 
I made a mistake: 
U can use *example.com* for *first.example.com* and for *second.first.example.com*. 
But u can not use **.example.com* for *second.first.example.com*. Wildcard certificate for **.example.com* support only first-level domain, but not support second-level. (For second level u need cert **.example.com*)

Comment: *.example.com can use example.com?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand question. *.example.com is the good mask for www.example.com, but not for example.com.

Comment: I found that example.com can use *.example.com. so I puzzled. like the question. I am very confused, what is the difference between this certificate and the pan-domain certificate such as *.1991421.cn.

Comment: I understand!!! 
U can use example.com for first.example.com and for second.first.example.com. \
But u can not use *.example.com for second.first.example.com. Wildcard certificate for *.example.com support inly first-level domain, but not support second-level. (For second level u need cert *.*.example.com)